# bluetooth environmental sensing service temperature characteristic

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The Bluetooth spec for the environmental sensing service (ESS) defines the [temperature characteristic](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.temperature.xml&u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.temperature.xml&_ga=1.83464785.617775360.1471029783) as sint16 format.

However the resolution is listed as "0.01 degrees celcius". I cannot for the life of me understand how a sint16 datatype will represent decimal values. Shouldn't the format be of type float32? What am I missing here?

Comment: May the missing information be on this line: `Exponent: Decimal, -2`?

Comment: ah, so whatever the sint16 value x .01 to get the decimal value, is that how its supposed to be used?

Comment: Yes. I just tested it with nRF Toolbox / Connect and a modified GATT server example from the EPS-IDF library.